# TPA3112D1 PCB design no output sound

Tags: amplifier, pcb-design, audio, schematics, sound

I'm still learning about electronics and wanted to make a simple 25W class D audio amplifier circuit as a hobby project. The circuit I made is inspired by the [TPA3112D1 Evaluation Module](https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/slou272a/slou272a.pdf). The datasheet of the TPA3112D1 can be found [here](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tpa3112d1.pdf). The schematics are made in EasyEDA and are shown below, together with the layout of the PCB (ground planes were hidden for clarity). However, after ordering the PCB and connecting the board to a [Lab Bench Power Supply](https://eleshop.eu/owon-spe3103-power-supply.html) using 24V and connecting the output to a speaker, there is no sound at all. Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong? Or has any tips in general about the schematics/PCB layout? Any help is much appreciated.

I have measured/tried the following for debugging:

- TP0 = 0V.
- TP1 = 0.1V (after button pressed it's 0V).
- TP2 = between 0.7V and 7V and changing when rotating potentiometer.
- TP3 = 20V, when button pressed it's 0V.
- PVCC = 23.7V.
- AVCC = 23.7V.
- I noticed that I switched/reversed AVCC and PVCC (over the switch and 10 ohm resistor R4), but I don't think this is causing the issue.
- I can hear a soft irregular tick on the speaker, which disappears when I press the button.
- IN_P and IN_N are biased at 3V.
- GVDD is 7V.
- I desoldered the small ferrite beads, and kept the big ones which are in parallel, but this did not make a difference.
- Pressing the button during startup did not work.
- Current draw of the circuit is about 0.1A.

[image: TopLayerPCB]

[image: BottomLayerPCB]

[image: AmplifierSchematics]

[image: IO_Schematics]

**EDIT after comments:**

The pin header/jumper configurations used are (enabled = jumper connected, disabled = not connected):

- H1: Enabled
- H2: Enabled
- H3: Enabled
- H4: Disabled
- H5: Disabled
- H6: Disabled
- H7: Enabled

The signal measured with my oscilloscope on the Fault/GND pins looks as follows:
[image: Fault_GND_Scope]

Images of the top and bottom of the physical PCB:

[image: top_pcb]
[image: bottom_pcb]

Comment: connect an audio source to the inputs

Comment: @jsotola thanks for the suggestion, but I did plug a 3.5mm audio cable from the audio source (my pc) to the input of the board

Comment: I can confirm all your voltages compared to my board, except I have a resistor of 100 k to AVCC at pin 2, the /FAULT output. Can you place a jumper at H7/1-2 to measure the /FAULT output? Do you see the square wave at the outputs on a scope?

Comment: Did you link H1/1-2 to connect 3.5mm jack SGND to GND?

Comment: @Jens thank you for your comments. See the updated answer, I did connect SGND and GND. I added a screenshot of the measurement using an oscilloscope of the FAULT pin to GND.

Comment: So the chip sees an output shortcut and retires periodically. The try should be visible with a scope at the outputs. The only narrow gap I can see in the layout, is the track at the bottom left corner of C11. Do you have a photo of the board?

Comment: Just found in the datasheet page 13: A DC Detect Fault is issued when the output differential duty-cycle exceeds 14% (for example, +57%, -43%) for more than 420 ms at the same polarity. This feature protects the speaker from large DC currents or AC currents less than 2 Hz. To avoid nuisance faults due to the DC detect circuit, hold the SD pin low at power-up until the signals at the inputs are stable.

Comment: @Jens Added a photo of the board []. Good observation about C11. I measured with a multimeter and there's no short between the two pins. I tried pressing the button at power-on but this did not work unfortunately [Edited by a moderator to remove obsolete mention of an answer - the added images are now in the question.]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137226/discussion-between-jens-and-thomas).